# Find x for $ 5^{\frac{x}{2}} - 2^ x = 1 $ without guessing.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$ 5^{\frac{x}{2}} - 2^ x = 1 $$ Find x

Now at first glance , it is obvious that the answer is $x=2$(Might be another one maybe which is not so obvious) . But that is by hit and trial. What is the proper proof of it ??? Because of the different bases , I could not come up with any way to solve it.. please help.

Comment: the function $f(x)=5^{x/2}-2^x$ increases montonically to infinity, as $f(0)=0$ there is a unique solution to $f(x)=1$.  Usually you need to solve these sorts of things numerically, I wouldn't expect a sensible closed form solution in general.

Comment: @lulu Oh ok, I was expecting taht there might be a precaculus type of solution which would not require use of graphs as such but some easier manipulation. Thank you so much

Comment: I wouldn't expect much.  The equation $f(x)=2$, for instance, hasn't got any kind of nice solution. Just $2.5824121\dots$.

Comment: @lulu: it only increases monotonically for $x \gt -1.3377\ldots$.  Perhaps you could say $f(x)=(\sqrt{5})^x-2^x$ is only positive for $x \gt 0$ and then it is monotonically increasing

Comment: @Henry  Absolutely true.  I had meant to include the condition $x≥0$, but left it off.

Comment: Finding the solution without guessing is difficult (certainly not precalculus by any stretch).

Answer (score 4):

Hit and trial is a fine proof that $2$ is a solution.  To show that there are no more, you can write your equation as $$(\sqrt 5)^x-2^x=1$$ and note that the derivative of the left hand side is $\log \sqrt 5 (\sqrt 5)^x-\log 2\cdot 2^x$ which is positive for $x \ge 0$, while for $x \lt 0$ the left side is less than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytical method to solve this equation.

The solution $x=2$ if found by successive approximation methods.

Start at some initial point and follow the iterations $$ x_0, f(x_o),f(f(x_0)),...$$ and it approaches to $2$

That is the only solution for the given equation due to the exponential nature of the LHS expression.